# My Queue implementation is correct?

Tags: c, queue

I have read CLRS Introduction to Algorithms book, now I'm on Elementary data structure chapter. I read about queue concept and try to implement in c.
I have tested a lot it work fine, but I have a little doubt on its working. Please tell me this implementation is correct or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 4
struct queue {
    int array[MAX];
    int head;
    int tail;   
};
void ENQUEUE(struct queue* p,int data) {
// error checking for overflow
    if((p->tail == MAX-1 && p->head == 0 ) || (p->head == p->tail+1)) {
        printf("\nQUEUE IS FULL!!   ");
        return;
    }
    p->array[p->tail] = data; 
    if(p->tail == MAX-1)
        p->tail = 0;
    else
        p->tail = p->tail+1;
    printf("\n%d data is added",data);
}

int DEQUEUE(struct queue* p) {
    if(p->head == p->tail) {
        printf("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY!!");
        return -1;
    }
    int x = p->array[p->head];
    if(p->head == MAX-1)
        p->head = 0;
    else
        p->head = p->head+1;
    printf("\n%d data is removed",x);
    return x;
}
void SHOWQUEUE(struct queue* p) {
    int i = 0;
    i = p->head;
    printf("p->head = %d & p->tail = %d",p->head,p->tail);
    printf("\nQUEUE ELEMENTS:");

    while(i != p->tail) {
        printf("%d ",p->array[i]);
        if(i == (MAX-1)) 
            i = 0;

        else
            i = i+1;
    }
}
int main() {
    struct queue* Q;
    Q = (struct queue*) malloc(sizeof (struct queue));
    if(Q == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return -1;
    }
    Q->head = 1;
    Q->tail = 1; 
/*  ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);

    ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    printf("head = %d & tail = %d ",Q->head,Q->tail);
*/
    ENQUEUE(Q,98);
    ENQUEUE(Q,20);
    ENQUEUE(Q,16);
    ENQUEUE(Q,2);
//  ENQUEUE(Q,1);
//  ENQUEUE(Q,2);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,5);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,3);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,10);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);   
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,12);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,2);
    DEQUEUE(Q);

    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    ENQUEUE(Q,1);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    DEQUEUE(Q);
    SHOWQUEUE(Q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say `but I have a little doubt on its working` what you mean by you doubt it's working ? Is it throwing exceptions ? Is one of the operation failing ?  Normally broken code is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: If you have doubts about its correctness then maybe you should write two or three additional test cases. Or two or three million additional test cases; you could write a program that writes test cases. Whatever it takes to make you feel like its correct.

Answer (score 1):

**1** It would be more natural to have a field **`size`** instead of **`tail`**:

```
struct queue {
    int array[MAX];
    int head;
    int tail;   
};
```

**2** If you had **`size`** field, checking whether the queue is empty or 
full would be a simple one-liner.

```
    if((p->tail == MAX-1 && p->head == 0 ) || (p->head == p->tail+1)) {
        printf("\nQUEUE IS FULL!!   ");
        return;
    }
```

**3** It's not cool to print from algorithms unless debugging.

```
int DEQUEUE(struct queue* p) {
    if(p->head == p->tail) {
        printf("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY!!");
        return -1;
    }
```

**4** Can make the output of this more pretty.

```
void SHOWQUEUE(struct queue* p) {
    ...
}
```

**5** The convention is not to prepend **`malloc`** with a type.

```
Q = (struct queue*) malloc(sizeof (struct queue));
```

Instead, do this

```
Q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
```

**6** Don't do this:

```
Q->head = 1;
Q->tail = 1;
```

Instead, you should write the function that initializes your queue.

**7** Above, it's funny that you start indexing from 1.

**Summa summarum**

You could consider something like the following:

**queue.h**:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CAPACITY 10

typedef struct queue {
    int storage[CAPACITY];
    size_t head;
    size_t size;
} queue;

void queue_init(queue* q);
bool queue_enqueue(queue* q, int element);
int  queue_dequeue(queue* q);
void queue_print(queue* q);

#endif
```

**queue.c**

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void queue_init(queue* q)
{
    if (!q) 
    {
        return;
    }

    q->head = 0;
    q->size = 0;
}

bool queue_enqueue(queue* q, int element)
{
    if (!q || q->size == CAPACITY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    q->storage[(q->head + q->size++) % CAPACITY] = element;
    return true;
}

int queue_dequeue(queue* q)
{
    if (!q || q->size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int ret = q->storage[q->head];
    q->head = (q->head + 1) % CAPACITY;
    q->size--;
    return ret;
}

void queue_print(queue* q)
{
    if (!q)
    {
        printf("null");
        return;
    }

    printf("[");

    for (size_t i = 0, index = q->head; i < q->size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", q->storage[index]);

        if (i < q->size - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }

        index = (index + 1) % CAPACITY;
    }

    printf("]");
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    queue q;
    queue_init(&q);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        queue_enqueue(&q, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        queue_print(&q);
        puts("");
        queue_enqueue(&q, queue_dequeue(&q));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: #2 unclear: Why not simply (with size field) `if(p->tail == MAX-1) { printf("\nQUEUE IS FULL!!   ...`?

Comment: #5 IMO: `Q = malloc(sizeof *Q);` is even more idiomatic, easier to code and maintain.

Comment: A test of `if (!q)` in `queue_init(queue* q)` would make it symmetric with other functions.  Unclear why missing here and used in the other 3.